# Ms Access/ SQL query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table as below. Need a Query to select the Last activity of the User. (There should not be multiple listing for same user, Single user single row)

[image: Click here for Table]

```
+----------------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+
|      Date      | BOT_ID  |      Process       |  LastModified   |   Status   |
+----------------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 1  | Interaction record | 9/19/2017 10:50 | In Process |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 2  | Single Assessed    | 9/26/2017 12:00 | In process |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 3  | Interaction record | 9/26/2017 11:35 | Completed  |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 4  | Metering           | 9/26/2017 11:50 | In proce   |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 1  | Move In            | 9/26/2017 11:50 | In process |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 4  | Interaction record | 9/26/2017 11:58 | Completed  |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 5  | Direct Debit       | 9/26/2017 11:10 | Completed  |
| 17/09/26 00:00 | User 17 | latest             | 9/26/2017 0:15  | In Process |
+----------------+---------+--------------------+-----------------+------------+
```

Comment: And the question is ??

Comment: Is your question about Access or MySQL? Please only use the appropriate tag.

Comment: In MySQL it would be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column?rq=1 Maybe it's similar in Access.

Comment: pls next time avoid using images and use text as above edited question

Comment: Etsa..How to do that..? I'm new to StackOverflow.

Comment: read introduction to SO.  Doing this effort help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query.  The subselect calculate max(lastmodified) for each user, using GROUP BY.  The result is joined to main table using BOT_ID and the calculated date with lastmodified date.  If a user has two same date lastmodified, both the rows will be returned:

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM YOURTABLE A
INNER JOIN (SELECT BOT_ID, MAX(LASTMODIFIED) AS LAST_ACTIVITY 
            FROM YOURTABLE 
            GROUP BY BOT_ID) B ON A.BOT_ID=B.BOT_ID AND A.LASTMODIFIED = B.LAST_ACTIVITY
```

Comment: Yeai.. that worked. Thanks esta.
Small modification, used Last() instead of max()

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Select Max([Last Modified]) As [Last Activity] 
From YourTable 
Where BOT_ID = "User 1"
```

To list all:

```
Select BOT_ID, Max([Last Modified]) As [Last Activity] 
From YourTable 
Group By BOT_ID
```

Comment: But, I need Last activity for Each User listed.

Comment: Well, see extended answer.